# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении:"Заменительное приложение может состоять из тех же букв, при условии если есть дополнительное разъяснение"?

Comment: Еще бы смысл этого понять... Что за приложение из букв? Впрочем,"к детям, которых я тут представляю, это не имеет никакого отношения"

Comment: Не грузитесь, это арабская грамота.

Comment: Я так и поняла, что это что-то специальное. Важно, чтобы смысл не влиял на пунктуацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, так как в языке встречаются составные производные союзы типа "в случае если, при условии если...", которые должны находиться в начале придаточного предложения

Answer (score 0):

Странен мне этот союз "при условии, если". Его первая часть выражает как бы констатацию, а вторая — предположение. ["При этом первый знак препинания обычно ставится между частями союза (после слов «при условии»)".](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_640)

Comment: В том-то и дело, что после слова "при условии" запятая не ставится, так же как внутри  многих других составных союзов типа "с тех пор как, до тех пор пока, ввиду того что, несмотря на то что и др."

Answer (score 0):

Пардон, конечно, но такого составного союза нет.